# Posting Dynamic HTML Form Through PrintWriter out.print(HTML Form) is not working Sometimes

Tags: java, html

I am making dynamic HTML Form  and trying to post it through PrintWriter class method ie out.print(Dynamic HTML Form)
But in browser it is not reflecting for few cases and it is working  for mostly cases.
My concern is when i am doing out.print(this below form ) ..its not working  sometimes and not getting reflected on browser.[test.html][1]
Below is my dynamic HTML code
My problem is in browser  it is waiting and when we are doing out.print(HTML Form) ,it is not reflecting in browser and getting stuck somewhere

Below  is Failure HTML----------

```
< html > < head > < Meta HTTP - EQUIV = "Cache-Control"
CONTENT = "no-cache" > < Meta HTTP - EQUIV = "Pragma"
CONTENT = "no-cache" > < Meta HTTP - EQUIV = "Expires"
CONTENT = "0" > < title > Card Info < /title><SCRIPT LANGUAGE = 
JavaScript>
<!--
isNN = document.layers ? 1 : 0;

function noContext() {
    return false;
}

function noClick(e) {
    if (isNN) {
            if (e.which > 1) {
            return false;
           }
    } else {
    if (event.button > 1) {
        return false;
        }
    }
}   
if (isNN) {
    document.captureEvents(Event.MOUSEDOWN);
}
document.oncontextmenu = noContext;
document.onmousedown = noClick;
document.onmouseup = noClick;
//-->
<
/SCRIPT> <
style type = "text/css" > body {
    font - family: Arial, Helvetica, sans - serif;
    font - weight: normal;
    color: #474747; font-size: 14px; margin:15% auto 0 auto; } # 
intermediatepage {
        background - image: url('/images/ccavenue_logo.gif');
        background - position: center top;
        background - repeat: no - repeat;
        padding: 10 px 20 px 0 20 px;
    }#
    intermediatepage div.process {
        background - image: url('/images/loader.gif');
        background - position: center 35 px;
        background - repeat: no - repeat;
    } < /style> </head > < body oncontextmenu = "return false;"
    onLoad = "document.MalltoEpay.submit();" > < label id = 
"requestId"
    style = "display:none;" > 109893762755 < /label><form name="MalltoEpay" method="POST" action="https://student.admin.com/receive/160/servlet/school/corporate " ><input type="
    hidden " name="
    response " value="
    B69C90C2E392FA361F622CBB9E8F6F96EB2759A6C7F674F3E91F35F3ADCF1B1969C8A0DEFAD9F40CC61B18377F39ED7AC28772589B089EFF091227D949D00C124BB6C0 "></form> <
        div id = "intermediatepage"
    align = "center" > < div class = "process" > < br / > < br / > < 
br / > < br / > < br / > < br / > < span class = "content-text"
    style = "font-size:24px; font-weight:bold;" > Please be patient
    while your task is being processed. < /span><br style="line- 
height:35px;" / > < span > Do not "close the window"
    or press "refresh"
    or "browser back/forward button". < /span><br / > < br / > < /div> 
   </div > < /body></html >
```

---

Success HTML which worked---

```
            < html > < head > < Meta HTTP - EQUIV = "Cache-Control"
CONTENT = "no-cache" > < Meta HTTP - EQUIV = "Pragma"
CONTENT = "no-cache" > < Meta HTTP - EQUIV = "Expires"
CONTENT = "0" > < title > Card Info < /title><SCRIPT LANGUAGE = 
JavaScript>
<!--
isNN = document.layers ? 1 : 0;

function noContext() {
    return false;
}

function noClick(e) {
    if (isNN) {
        if (e.which > 1) {
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        if (event.button > 1) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
if (isNN) {
    document.captureEvents(Event.MOUSEDOWN);
}
document.oncontextmenu = noContext;
document.onmousedown = noClick;
document.onmouseup = noClick;
//-->
<
/SCRIPT> <
style type = "text/css" > body {
        font - family: Arial, Helvetica, sans - serif;
        font - weight: normal;
        color: #474747; font-size: 14px; margin:15% auto 0 auto; } # 
intermediatepage {
            background - image: url('/images/ccavenue_logo.gif');
            background - position: center top;
            background - repeat: no - repeat;
            padding: 10 px 20 px 0 20 px;
        }#
            intermediatepage div.process {
            background - image: url('/images/loader.gif');
            background - position: center 35 px;
            background - repeat: no - repeat;
        } < /style> </head > < body oncontextmenu = "return false;"
        onLoad = "document.MalltoEpay.submit();" > < label id = 
"requestId"
       style = "display:none;" > 109893460134 < /label><form 
   name="MalltoEpay" method="POST" 
action="https://student.admin.com/receive/160/servlet/school/corporate 
" ><input type="
    hidden " name="
    response " value="
    741 D2861F31A8AEA57B3F33EC204C7243E41DE1721FFA088AD1C6E6A7C490586E2D0345CE84657A9A10996FE55C3FEAB533768AEF942E495D285E1A6917B131 "></form> <
        div id = "intermediatepage"
    align = "center" > < div class = "process" > < br / > < br / > < 
br / > < br / > < br / > < br / > < span class = "content-text"
    style = "font-size:24px; font-weight:bold;" > Please be patient
    while your task is being processed. < /span><br style="line- 
   height:35px;" / > < span > Do not "close the window"
    or press "refresh"
    or "browser back/forward button". < /span><br / > < br / > < /div> 
   </div > < /body></html >
```

Out of 10 request 3 request is not working...

Comment: can you please give code rather than image

Comment: I have added code thank you in advance

Comment: your codes looks like minified and its hard to check for the bugs so, make some edit

Comment: i have unminified the code